# fit_generator() missing 1 required positional argument: 'generator'

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

Need help in figuring this out. I'm not sure what went wrong but the error persists. Looked around but can't find a similar issue.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import os
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid
import math
%matplotlib inline
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Model

batch_size=32
datagen_args = dict(rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
                   rescale=1./255)
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**datagen_args)
train_datagenerator = datagen.flow_from_directory('/content/drive/MyDrive/cats_dogs_small/train',target_size=(128,128),
                                            batch_size=batch_size,interpolation="lanczos",shuffle=True)
valid_datagenerator = datagen.flow_from_directory('/content/drive/MyDrive/cats_dogs_small/validation',target_size=(128,128),
                                            batch_size=batch_size,interpolation="lanczos",shuffle=True)

epochs = 25
hist = Model.fit_generator(train_datagenerator, 
                           steps_per_epoch= math.ceil(train_datagenerator.samples//batch_size),
                           epochs=epochs, validation_data=valid_datagenerator, validation_steps=math.ceil(valid_datagenerator.samples//batch_size),verbose = 1, workers=8)
```

The error msg is as such:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-178574fd407f> in <module>()
      2 hist = Model.fit_generator(train_datagenerator, 
      3                            steps_per_epoch= math.ceil(train_datagenerator.samples//batch_size),
----> 4                            epochs=epochs, validation_data=valid_datagenerator, validation_steps=math.ceil(valid_datagenerator.samples//batch_size),verbose = 1, workers=8)

TypeError: fit_generator() missing 1 required positional argument: 'generator'
```

Comment: Model is a class, in which variable is your model held?

Comment: You said you needed help but then ignore people asking clarifications from your question? This is is not really answerable until you define where your model is in this code.

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply! I just managed to tried this again yesterday. I have figured it out now. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

fit generator is depreciated, just use model.fit. Note you used Model.fit_generator. You should use model.fit.

Comment: The author is using keras, not tf.keras, deprecation is irrelevant here as it is not the actual problem. fit_generator is only deprecated in tf.keras

Answer (score 0):

I realized I did not define what model is. Added the layers, compiled and tried again it works this time. I'm new in this, still got lots to learn !